# Disable Wifi on HP P1102W

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I have several HP P1102W Laserjet printers.  The WiFi is enabled by default.  How can I disable it permanently?  There is also a hardware WiFi button, is it possible to disable that button to prevent a user from enabling the WiFi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These printers are not designed for a corporate environment or advance printer management. They are designed as Small Office/Home Office printers and these don't generally allow such access restriction.

However, have you checked the administrative web control panel? There may be an option to prevent enabling wireless using the button.

Comment: Agreed. I wish the correct printers had been ordered.   The configuration page, allows me to disable the WiFi, but pressing the hardware WiFi button enables it again.   I may have to disconnect the antennae in the printer.

Comment: That or disconnect the button.

Comment: The correct answer is that these are not designed for the enterprise. and should not be used in that environment. To disable WiFi permanently, I had to disassemble the printer and disconnect the antenna.  This does not scale well.

Comment: This scalability of this fix varies inversely to the value of the number referred to by the word "several". :)